# Why do I get an immediate error on balance start

Tags: btrfs

I am most of the way through converting a raid1 mdadm with lvm on top to a btrfs system.  the two disks/partitions involved are on `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`.

In the original configuration both disks had 3 partitions and device `/dev/md1` was made up of `/dev/sdb3` and `/dev/sdc3`. The conversion process was as follows

1. fail and then remove /dev/sdb3
2. use fdisk to repartition /dev/sdb into 4 partitions - I couldn't sync kernel to new partiion layout so rebooted
3. made a btrfs filesystem on `/dev/sdb4` (also on `/dev/sdb2` but thats not important here) size 1.7TB
4. created a mount point on `/mnt/sdb4` created subvolumes to correspond to each of my logical volumes on my (now degraded) raid device.  One of these (`vbox`) was to hold virtual box images, so I did `chattr +C /mnt/sdb4/vbox`
5. User rsync to copy each of my logical volumes on the raid device to the appropriate subvolume on btrfs.  As each completed I unmounted the raid volume, adjusted `/etc/fstab` to now mount using the btrfs subvolume and then mounted it.  When all this completed I rebooted to be sure it all came up properly.
6. I then removed all the logical volumes and finally the volume group from the raid array, and then stopped and deleted the raid device. Rebooted once more
7. Used `fdisk` to repartition `/dev/sdc`  to the similar 4 partitions on `/dev/sdb`  I made and independant btrfs filesystem in `/dev/sdc2`
8. I mounted `/dev/sdb4` (subvol=/) on `/mnt/sdb4` and then issued the following command `btrfs device add -f /dev/sdc4 /mnt/sdb4`
9. Finally I issued this command `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/sdb4`  HOWEVER this failed with "ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt/sdb4': No space left on device
   There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail"

I tried looking in syslog as recommended, but that doesn't help

`[  634.536221] BTRFS info (device sdb4): disk added /dev/sdc4
[  671.472167] BTRFS info (device sdb4): relocating block group 12582912 flags 1
[  671.934540] BTRFS info (device sdb4): found 946 extents
[  672.622029] BTRFS info (device sdb4): found 946 extents
[  672.913928] BTRFS info (device sdb4): 379 enospc errors during balance`

The output from `btrfs fi show` is

```
Label: 'raid'  uuid: c3356f85-4b40-409d-a775-72e9c6735ed8
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 377.08GiB
    devid    1 size 1.71TiB used 379.02GiB path /dev/sdb4
    devid    2 size 1.00KiB used 0.00B path /dev/sdc4

Label: 'debianb'  uuid: 94a949e0-b815-4dce-812d-7000f4654a10
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 285.25MiB
    devid    1 size 100.00GiB used 3.02GiB path /dev/sdb2

Label: 'debianc'  uuid: 02ed1d78-8501-4940-ac61-fa9dcf084b56
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 112.00KiB
    devid    1 size 100.00GiB used 2.02GiB path /dev/sdc2
```

Which shows plenty of space.

I am doing all of this on `debian stretch`

So why is the no space left on device being reported, and what can I do to get this filesystem properly converted to raid1?

Answer (score 0):

My fault I think.  I screwed up partitioning `/dev/sdc` so the 4th partition was zero length.